# Change size of capped collection MongoDB preserving indexes

Tags: mongodb

I have a lot of big collections (2GB) and I want to increase it's size. To do this I can:

1) Create new one, copy data, rename it (it takes a lot of time to copy all this data)

2) If I want only to increase collection size I can use "convertToCapped" but it also removes all indexes, recreating indexes takes in my case about 10 min

Do you have any other ideas how to increase size of capped collection preserving all indexes?

Comment: I saw this and they are describing this 2 points

Comment: StackOverflow has changed since the question was originally asked and this is really more of a DBA question which is better suited to [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com), which is just one of the sites spawned to keep non-programming topics off of this site. The referenced question does basically describe the process and should give enough to point to that "capped collections cannot be 're-sized' in place" which is the general point.